# Git - How to get the latest code of Branch a from Branch B without switching branches

Tags: git, github, version-control

I am newbie to GIT. I am trying to figure out the answer for the below scenario.

I have user story say story1. There are two subtask for the user story 
1) UI part
2) REST Code

We create a branch for the user story say feature/STORY1
Two teams are working on the STORY1. One on the UI part and other team on the REST part. So we created branches for feature/STORY1 say 
feature/STORY1-UI
feature/STORY1-REST

feature/STORY1-UI
feature/STORY1-REST are created under feature/STORY1.

My scenario:
While I am working on STORY1-UI I need the latest code from STORY1-REST as my UI development needs the rest code. How can I get the latest code from STORY1-REST branch without switching my branch from STORY1-UI.

The best solution would have been not to split into sub branches.But since the branching is already done,I need a solution for this scenario.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you mean you want to get the REST code in the UI branch, you should just merge in REST. Make sure you've checked out the feature/STORY1-UI branch, and then run

```
git merge feature/STORY1-REST
```

Check out http://www.git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging for the basics of branching and merging.

Comment: Then a merge is exactly what you need. It will merge in all commits on the REST branch into your current branch (so as long as your current branch is UI, you're set).

Answer (score 1):

If you are working on both branch using the same local machine, then you can simply merge the other branch by `git merge` like below

```
git merge feature/STORY1-REST
```

But I think you are working on different machines. Then you should upload the code on some code hosting site to pull the changes done on other machines. [github.com](http://github.com) and [bitbucket.com](http://bitbucket.com) are two good sites for code hosting, where [bitbucket.com](http://bitbucket.com) offers private repositories for free.

In this case, you can `git push` feature/STORY1-REST to the repository from one machine and then pull the branch from other machines, using `git pull`

```
git pull origin feature/STORY1-REST
```

-here `origin` is an alias of your repository.

Details are available here https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/